# Add routerlink to Vuetify data table row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` that gets the data from API. I want to make the rows clickable and if the user clicks one row, it will open another route and show the complete data from that one row. How to make this happen with `v-data-table`?

template

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="visitors"
        :search="search"
        class="elevation-1"
>
```

data

```
data() {
    return {
      visitors: []
    }
}
```

methods

```
async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/visitors`);
      this.visitors = res.data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to where I should put the router link? Or is there any other way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on v-data-table you can add `@click:row="yourMethod"`. Here's an example:

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="visitors"
        :search="search"
        class="elevation-1"
        @click:row="openDetails"
>
```

and then your method (just an example):

```
openDetails(val) {
  this.$router.push("details/"val.id)
}
```

Comment: for styling you can add style="cursor:pointer;" on v-data-table